# mysql array in field join with other table

Tags: mysql, join, field

I have 2 tables: `reason`, `user`

```
reason (id, reason)
user (id, name, reason_id)
```

in data:

```
reason (1, 'ok'), (2, 'no problem')
user (1, 'eko', '1,2')
```

I need view like this:

```
    id | name | reason
    1  | eko  | ok, no problem
```

is that possibly to doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id,u.name,r.reason 
from user u left join reason r 
on u.reason_id = r.id;
```

Comment: That won't work. You're trying to join on "1,2" which doesn't exist

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21456142)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT
    a.id, 
    a.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.reason ORDER BY b.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS reason
FROM
    user a
INNER JOIN
    reason b ON SUBSTRING(a.reason, FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.reason) + (FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.reason) - 1), 1) = b.id
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

As a sidenote, what you have is a terrible database design. The relationship between `users` and `reasons` is a N:M (many-to-many) relationship. *One user may have many reasons; one reason may be had by many users*...

The best way to model this relationship is to use a cross-reference table that stores the unique combinations of `userid` and `reasonid`:

```
+-------------+   +-------------------+   +---------------+
| users       |   | users_has_reasons |   | reasons       |
+-------------+   +-------------------+   +---------------+
| userid [PK] |   | userid [PK]       |   | reasonid [PK] |
| name        |   | reasonid [PK]     |   | reason        |
| etc...      |   +-------------------+   | etc...        |
+-------------+                           +---------------+
```

Then to get the same result, you can just do:

```
SELECT
    a.userid, 
    a.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.reason ORDER BY c.reasonid SEPARATOR ', ') AS reason
FROM
    users a
INNER JOIN
    users_has_reasons b ON a.userid = b.userid
INNER JOIN 
    reasons c ON b.reasonid = c.reasonid
GROUP BY
    a.userid
```

Which is **MUCH** more efficient as your joins will be happening over indexes, and also **MUCH** easier to manage (i.e. insert, update, delete, etc.).

Comment: i'm sorry to continue my ask, sorry to my friend zane bien, coz my problem still not finish, in your code just one row that viewed in my table, any other ideas?

Comment: @ElvisSonathaDanListi How many distinct id's do you have in your table?

Comment: apologize earlier, there are actually three tables namely flag_detail, users and flag_rules
so for example if the table is filled it will be:
name | pictures    | rules          | comment
1    | avatar.jpg  | good, perfect  | ok
2    | avatar1.jpg | pretty, pretty | not used
3    | avatar2.jpg | big, slippery  | do
rules of flag_rules, in the rules table contents: 1. good 2. perfect 3. enough 4. pretty 5. big 6. slippery
in flag_detail column contains only rules' id's from the 'rules' such as 1.2 3.4 and so on. I mean the 'rules' 1.2 was replaced with the existing rules in the table flag_rules